# JQuery sound - playing and stopping?

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio

I wanted to implement something with JQuery (trying to avoid external plugins), that will play sound on clicking "play" and stop the sound by clicking "stop", and will also work cross-browser (including iPhone and iPad devices, so no flash).

Is there a solution to this?

I have only ever found external plugins..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately no. For years the only way to play audio in the browser has always required a plugin. More recently, the HTML5 standard has provided a cross-browser standard for playing audio. Unfortunately many browsers still don't implement HTML5, so this doesn't really fix your problem either.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Which plugin would you recommend for easy implementation with a small footprint?

Comment: That works across all browsers? It doesn't exist. I hate to say it, but there's a reason flash has been so popular, it covers a pretty good percentage of the market.

Comment: Thanks Chris. It's a real shame that browsers can't just get up to HTML5 standard already. I'll have to try find a plugin that works on most browsers.. if you do have one that you could recommend that'd be great! Thanks again.